# Debugging R Scripts in azure-ml: Where can stdout and stderr logs be found? (or why are they empty?)

Tags: r, azure, machine-learning, rstudio, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using "studio (preview)" from Microsoft Azure Machine Learning to create a pipeline that applies machine learning to a dataset in a blob storage that is connected to our data warehouse.

In the "Designer", an "Exectue R Script" action can be added to the pipeline. I'm using this functionality to execute some of my own machine learning algorithms.

I've got a 'hello world' version of this script working (including using the "script bundle" to load the functions in my own R files). It applies a very simple manipulation (compute the days difference with the date in the date column and 'today'), and stores the output as a new file. Given that the exported file has the correct information, I know that the R script works well.

The script looks like this:

```
# R version: 3.5.1
# The script MUST contain a function named azureml_main
# which is the entry point for this module.

# The entry point function can contain up to two input arguments:
#   Param<medals>: a R DataFrame
#   Param<matches>: a R DataFrame

azureml_main <- function(dataframe1, dataframe2){

  message("STARTING R script run.")

  # If a zip file is connected to the third input port, it is
  # unzipped under "./Script Bundle". This directory is added
  # to sys.path.

  message('Adding functions as source...')

  if (FALSE) {
    # This works...
      source("./Script Bundle/first_function_for_script_bundle.R")
  } else {
    # And this works as well!
    message('Sourcing all available functions...')
    functions_folder = './Script Bundle'

    list.files(path = functions_folder)
    list_of_R_functions <- list.files(path = functions_folder, pattern = "^.*[Rr]$", include.dirs = FALSE, full.names = TRUE)
    for (fun in list_of_R_functions) {

      message(sprintf('Sourcing <%s>...', fun))

      source(fun)

    }
  }

  message('Executing R pipeline...')
  dataframe1 = calculate_days_difference(dataframe = dataframe1)

  # Return datasets as a Named List
  return(list(dataset1=dataframe1, dataset2=dataframe2))
}
```

And although I do print some messages in the R Script, I haven't been able to find the "stdoutlogs" nor the "stderrlogs" that should contain these printed messages.

I need the printed messages for 1) information on how the analysis went and -most importantly- 2) debugging in case the code failed.

Now, I have found (on multiple locations) the files "stdoutlogs.txt" and "stderrlogs.txt". These can be found under "Logs" when I click on "Exectue R Script" in the "Designer".
I can also find "stdoutlogs.txt" and "stderrlogs.txt" files under "Experiments" when I click on a finished "Run" and then both under the tab "Outputs" and under the tab "Logs".
However... all of these files are empty.

Can anyone tell me how I can print messages from my R Script and help me locate where I can find the printed information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please click on the "Execute R module" and download the 70_driver.log? I tried message("STARTING R script run.") in an R sample and can found the output there.

[image: view logs for a execute R script module]

Comment: Ah yes, that's the one. I shouldn't have let myself get distracted by the filenames "stderrlogs.txt" and "stdoutlogs.txt" under "logs" in the same section.

Comment: We will improve our documentation to better explain how to look for these outputs and logs.

Comment: Hi again.. It seems that the interface has changed. Looks a bit better, but when I try to look up the issue in the R script, I can't seem to find the information anymore. At some point in the "70_driver_log.txt" it now says "... (omitted 171 lines) ..."... Any idea how I can access those 171 omitted lines?

Comment: Can you please share with us the 70 driver log?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. The issue was related to problems at the start of the R Script: the dataframe was too large. It worked when I created a smaller version of the dataset. In my experience, the errors at the start and end (i.e., with the dataframes at the start, or dataframes at the end) the script are the most difficult to detect.  For example, if the R script is trying to export an empty dataframe, it's very obscure to understand this from the available error logs (I now wrote my own error checks for such issues).